# Como simplificar esta função que tem parâmetros enviados

Tags: javascript

Amigos estou iniciando com javascript e me deparei com uma dúvida que pelo meu nível certamente é comum está dúvida.

O objetivo deste código é localizar por id, ou classe, que são vários inputs no qual preciso popular o options, sem a necessidade de editar isso no HTML.

Vejam o código a seguir

```
let createOptions = function(id,ranger){

  let select = document.getElementById(id)
  let numberOptionsStart = 0
  let maxNumberOptions = ranger

  if(select != null || select != undefined){
    for (let maxInputCounter = numberOptionsStart; maxInputCounter <= maxNumberOptions; maxInputCounter++)
      {
          let opt = document.createElement('option')
          opt.value = maxInputCounter
          opt.innerHTML = maxInputCounter
          select.appendChild(opt)
      }
  }
}

createOptions('Periodo1Dupla1',25)
createOptions('Periodo1Dupla2',25)

createOptions('Periodo2Dupla1',25)
createOptions('Periodo2Dupla2',25)

createOptions('Periodo3Dupla1',25)
createOptions('Periodo3Dupla2',25)

createOptions('ProrrogacaoDupla1',25)
createOptions('ProrrogacaoDupla2',25)

createOptions('PenaltisDupla1',25)
createOptions('PenaltisDupla2',25)

createOptions('FinalDupla1',2)
createOptions('FinalDupla2',2)

createOptions('FinalEquipe1',25)
createOptions('FinalEquipe2',25)
```

Eu tentei usar document.querySelectorAll, separando por virgula as ID´s e não consegui fazer a inserção dos options. Então minha dúvida é como simplificar este código para evitar essa cascata de chamada da mesma função.

Comment: É realmente para povoar os ```Selects``` com números de 1 a 25? Não tem nenhuma aplicação prática?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez a intenção de popular na verdade são os gols ou pontos de equipes ou duplas. (por exemplo futebol a contagem é de uma forma, tênis é outra formato a contagem), como são campeonatos diferentes, esportes diferentes, precisa ter variações no select

Comment: Você pode adaptar um pouquinho a função para chamar um array. Vou dar um exemplo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A meu ver, a forma mais didática é: você pode manter essa função para povoar um select, já que já está funcionando, e criar uma função nova que vai funcionar como adaptador: vai receber um array de pares (id, ranger) e vai iterar esse array chamando a sua função, que já funciona para um select.

Eu fiz isso abaixo, e escolhi colocar cada par identificador (id, ranger) num objeto, mas poderia ser adaptado para funcionar só com arrays sem problema.

Se tiver algum problema, fale nos comentários que a gente vê como pode ajudar.

```
let createOptionsForMultipleSelects = function(selectsAndRangesArray) {
  selectsAndRangesArray.forEach(selRangeObj => createOptions(selRangeObj))
}

let createOptions = function({id,ranger}){
  let select = document.getElementById(id)
  let numberOptionsStart = 0
  let maxNumberOptions = ranger

  if(select != null || select != undefined){
    for (let maxInputCounter = numberOptionsStart; maxInputCounter <= maxNumberOptions; maxInputCounter++)
      {
          let opt = document.createElement('option')
          opt.value = maxInputCounter
          opt.innerHTML = maxInputCounter
          select.appendChild(opt)
      }
  }
}

createOptionsForMultipleSelects([
  {id: 'Periodo1Dupla1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'Periodo1Dupla2', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'Periodo2Dupla1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'Periodo2Dupla2', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'Periodo3Dupla1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'Periodo3Dupla2', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'ProrrogacaoDupla1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'ProrrogacaoDupla2', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'PenaltisDupla1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'PenaltisDupla2', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'FinalDupla1', ranger: 2},
  {id: 'FinalDupla2', ranger: 2},
  {id: 'FinalEquipe1', ranger: 25},
  {id: 'FinalEquipe2', ranger: 25}
])
```

Comment: o que você fez ao meu ver é basicamente o que estava tentando fazer antes com o document.querySelectorAll('Periodo1Dupla1','Periodo1Dupla2,....) e não estava consenguindo até agora não entendi o porquê que não executava a função. De qualquer forma o que me incomodava muito é a repetição grande de chamada da mesma função (estava achando feio). Fazendo Como você fez deixou o código mais bonito, gostei mesmo. Obrigado pelo seu interesse, estou aprendendo e notei que POO é fundamental mesmo.

Comment: Se quiser mandar o código anterior pra ver se eu consigo entender o que estava dando erro, faz um edit e comenta aqui.